# Upsert and embedded documents in MongoEngine

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, upsert

I'm building a tool that pulls data out of an API and saves it to MongoDB. I'm using Python3 and MongoEngine for this.

I'm able to pull the data, and save it. This is how it looks in Mongo: https://pastebin.com/hjMtCznc

This is the Python code I use to save the data: 
https://pastebin.com/kqJw8VAc

This works. But I want to run this code every hour. Then If there's a new

```
   "campaign_id": "345775",
   "zone_id": "5609698",
```

I want to create this (upsert)

If the combination is already stored, I want to append the data to the embedded collections in this fashion.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ac8afa99d74e2e592586946"),
  "campaign_id": "345775",
  "zone_id": "5609698",
  "timeData": [
    {
      "t1": ISODate("2018-04-07T00:00:00Z"),
      "t2": ISODate("2018-04-07T13:46:48Z"),
      "clicks": 1,
      "unique_clicks": 1,
      "unique_visits": 15,
      "conversions": 1,
      "visits": 17,
      "payout": 80
    },
    {
      "t1": ISODate("2018-04-07T00:00:00Z"),
      "t2": ISODate("2018-04-07T14:46:48Z"),
      "clicks": 0,
      "unique_clicks": 0,
      "unique_visits": 1,
      "conversions": 0,
      "visits": 1,
      "payout": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the database structure I've defined in Pymongo: https://pastebin.com/1MreN3uB

I tried to do  `line.update(upsert=True)` instead of `line.save()`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a [Document update](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.update) to push `numline` into `timeData` field for TrackerData document all the while upserting when the document doesn't exist. *e.g.*

```
from mongoengine.errors import OperationError

try:
    (
        TrackerData.objects(
            campaign_id=doc["campaign_id"],
            zone_id=doc["token_1"]
        )
        .update(
            push__timeData=numline, upsert=True
        )
    )
except OperationError as e:
    logger.error(e)
```